# How to install different RAM modules

Tags: memory

I have different RAM modules - 2Rx8 and 2Rx4 . How can I install all of them in one server?
Tried putting all 2Rx8 in one Branch and 2Rx4 in another, but it didn't work.

```
    Branch0    |    Branch1
               |
  ChA  |  ChB  |  ChC  |  ChD  
|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
A A A A B B B B C C C C D D D D
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|
```

Possible modules

```
4 x 1GB 2Rx8
4 x 2GB 2Rx8
6 x 2GB 2Rx4
```

or

```
4 x 1GB 2Rx8
4 x 2GB 2Rx8
8 x 2GB 2Rx4
```

EDIT: Server Intel Server Board SR1560SF

Comment: This ENTIRELY depends on the exact server you're putting this into - and you've left that bit out - come back with the make/model - everything you can in fact - and then we might be able to help - but not until then ok.

Comment: Server model added.

Answer (score 4):

The [manual](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/s5400sf/sb/sr1560sf_serviceguide.pdf) shows you this:

[image]

So I'm thinking that A1,B1,C1 and D1 need to be all the same, then the same with A2,B2,C2, D2 and A3,B3,C3,D3 and finally A4,B4,C4,D4.

Comment: I am almost 100% sure that I tried also this config, but it didn't work. I'll try tomorrow again. At least now I know how it should be.